# Android - Change programmatically "Hide the status bar" setting inside Accesibility category on Settings App

Tags: android, settings, android-6.0-marshmallow, statusbar

I have not found this on Internet and thought that maybe someone here can give me a hand. I need to change programmatically the setting called "Hide the status bar" located in Accesibility inside the Android's Settings app. Next you can see it:

[image]

I have searched in Android's [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-cts-6.0_r32/core/java/android/provider/Settings.java), specifically in the android.provider.Settings class but have found nothing regarding it. I have also searched android.googlesource.com site via Google for the text "Hide the status bar" to see if maybe it was on some Strings file and see where it could be used.

Does someone know how to change this programmatically?

**EDIT**

forgot to mention that this is for Android Marshmallow (6.0).

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue? :)

Comment: @party-ring, no I didn't. I just asked the manufacture to set it to "On" but I wanted to change it within my app, which wasn't possible. Maybe if you look at the Android source code you can find how to set it.

Answer (score 0):

Write this in the `oncreate` of your activity.

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I am sorry but it does not. This is for a kiosk application not for a particular activity, that is why I am asking to change this particular setting. Thanks for trying though.

Comment: why don't you use this in the oncreate of all the activities? i know its a lousy approach but it'll get the work done.

Comment: Because the core app is not an Adobe AIR app, therefore you do not have access to the onCreate method of it's activity. I would have to add ANR which is much more work in comparison to changing programatically the mentioned parameter.